# Date range issue

Tags: asp.net

I have shifted our live server to a new server configuration Windows 2008 server and sql server 2008.

But  I am having following exception while adding date field data :

> 2011-05-15 18:00:44,263 ERROR Error
>   caught : the details of the error are 
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException:
>   SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between
>   1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999
>   11:59:59 PM.  at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan
>   value)

But the same code is working fine on local machine and was also working fine on old server.

I have even changed the date field explicitly into **"mm/dd/yy"** format.
But still not found the solution.
Can anyone provide me the solution.

Comment: Have you checked the regional settings from the old server match that of the new server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens because of server time format changed from your local system.

You should convert to dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss  which should work in all the systems.

Posting your code may suggest you with the modified code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here are a few links to help you with your problem, with what I have read it seems that

the `DataTime.MinValue` is equivalent to `00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.`

so you'll have to change that if you are using it, anyways here are the links

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399061/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-9999)

[link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx)

[link3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/1426459e-9d0a-4cf0-a1ef-55535e06c6ef)

Hope it helped !